# Two way comparison of 2 data tables in Separate sheets with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First question here. I was looking for a way to essentially compare 2 small data sets/tables and look for values in column a of table 1 that are additional or are not present in the 'master' table and include some message in a third column. This is in VBA.

It may be easier to explain what I'm hoping to get as output given 2 example tables.

Table 1 in columns a and b of Sheet1:

```
A       B
a12     horse

b23     dog

f54     cat
```

Table 2 in columns a and b of Sheet2:

```
A       B
b23     dog

f54     cat

i09     tiger
```

Desired output:

a12     horse      Warning: This is an additional value not present in Table 2

b23     dog

f54     cat

i09     tiger     Warning: This value was expected but not present in Table 1

Thanks for the help and let me know if there is additional detail  can provide to make this easier to answer

Comment: Did you find my answer useful? Please mark it as the answer if you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly be aware it is the same problem twice.

You essentially need to scan rows of table A to see if they are in table B.  Where they are output the row, where only table A has the row output the row with a message.

So you would do this firstly using table 1 as table A, then again but using table 2 as table B.  Adding the output of the second at the end of the first.

It's difficult to advise more without knowing more about your VBA ability.
Also your example provides two columns.  Do both columns need to be compared or do you just need to compare one?  I have assume both (worst case scenario).

You are really using the UNION set operator to add all unique rows so you might be able to adapt the method used [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BetterUnion.aspx) .  You have to adapt it as you want the text that describes which table a row was unique to.

Alternatively, you could do it writing VBA loops which would be something like this (which I think will give you what you need).

Paste this into a new module and run Main().  You will need to define the sheet and ranges.

```
Option Explicit

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim s2 As Worksheet
Dim sOutput As Worksheet
Dim NextOutputRow As Range


Sub CompareTwoTables(TableA As Range, TableB As Range, NameOfTableB As String, OutputIfRowsMatch As Boolean)

    Dim TableArow As Long
    Dim TableBrow As Long
    Dim TableACell As Range
    Dim TableBCell As Range
    Dim FoundMatchingRow As Boolean
    Dim ColumnDifferencesDetected As Boolean

    TableA.Parent.Select ' useful for debugging - selects teh sheet

    For TableArow = 1 To TableA.Rows.Count

        FoundMatchingRow = False

        For TableBrow = 1 To TableB.Rows.Count

            ColumnDifferencesDetected = False

            Set TableACell = TableA.Cells(TableArow, 1)
            Set TableBCell = TableB.Cells(TableBrow, 1)

            TableACell.Select ' useful for debugging
            Debug.Print TableACell.Address, TableBCell.Address ' useful for debugging

            If TableACell.Value = TableBCell.Value Then
                If TableA.Cells(TableArow, 2) = TableB.Cells(TableBrow, 2) Then
                    FoundMatchingRow = True
                Else
                    ColumnDifferencesDetected = True
                End If

            End If


            If FoundMatchingRow Or ColumnDifferencesDetected Then
                Exit For ' TableBrow
            End If

        Next TableBrow


        If FoundMatchingRow Then
            If OutputIfRowsMatch Then
                NextOutputRow.Cells(1, 1) = TableA.Cells(TableArow, 1)
                NextOutputRow.Cells(1, 2) = TableA.Cells(TableArow, 2)

                Set NextOutputRow = NextOutputRow.Offset(1, 0)

            End If

        ElseIf ColumnDifferencesDetected Then

            NextOutputRow.Cells(1, 1) = TableA.Cells(TableArow, 1)
            NextOutputRow.Cells(1, 2) = TableA.Cells(TableArow, 2)
            NextOutputRow.Cells(1, 2) = "One only one column was the same"

            Set NextOutputRow = NextOutputRow.Offset(1, 0)

        Else
            NextOutputRow.Cells(1, 1) = TableA.Cells(TableArow, 1)
            NextOutputRow.Cells(1, 2) = TableA.Cells(TableArow, 2)
            NextOutputRow.Cells(1, 3) = "This value was expected but not present in " & NameOfTableB

            Set NextOutputRow = NextOutputRow.Offset(1, 0)

        End If



    Next TableArow

End Sub

Sub main()

    Dim Table1 As Range
    Dim Table2 As Range

    ' Three sheets must exist
    Set s1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set sOutput = Worksheets("Sheet3")

    Set Table1 = s1.Range("A2:B10")  ' Allows for a title row and two columns
    Set Table2 = s2.Range("A2:B10")

    ' Clear any previous output
    sOutput.Cells.ClearContents

    Set NextOutputRow = sOutput.Range("2:2") ' Allows for a title row

    CompareTwoTables TableA:=Table1, TableB:=Table2, NameOfTableB:="Table2", OutputIfRowsMatch:=True

    CompareTwoTables TableA:=Table2, TableB:=Table1, NameOfTableB:="Table1", OutputIfRowsMatch:=False

    sOutput.Select

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```